# If a supernova explodes close to the centre of the milky way does its light get blueshifted by dark matter by the time it reaches the Earth?

Tags: galaxy, redshift, dark-matter

Does the dark matter halo of the milky way cause most of the change in wavelength or is baryonic matter responsible?

Comment: Why do you have the idea that a supernova's light would be "blueshifted" in the first place? (Are you somehow confusing "interstellar reddening" with blueshifting?)

Comment: @Peter Erwin I thought the dark matter halo with more mass than stars might dominate with most of its mass on the galaxy perimeter.

Comment: @DaveTheWave You are thinking that the dark matter halo should exert a gravitational pull outward? This does not happen, per the [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem).

Comment: @Sten I wasn't aware the halos are spherically symmetric shells

Comment: @DaveTheWave Halos are not exactly spherically symmetric, but they are close. Although the gravitational pull of a nonspherical shell is not exactly zero, the point stands that no outward force is expected. This is even true in highly nonspherical configurations, like galactic disks. A ring of mass can exert an outward pull, but a disk does not. Galaxies and dark matter halos almost invariably have more mass at lower radii than at higher radii.

Answer (score 7):

Light from the Galactic Center is gravitationally redshifted (not blueshifted) by a little over one part in a million as it climbs the Galactic potential to reach us. While dark matter contributes, stars are the dominant component of the Galaxy's mass below about the Sun's orbital radius (see for example figure 11 of [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.04557)).

Note that the great quantity of dark matter *above* the Sun's radius has no net gravitational influence, because the contributions of the portions of the dark matter halo that lie in different directions all cancel each other out. See the [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem).

It should also be noted that gravitational frequency shifts in nonrelativistic orbiting systems tend to be dwarfed by the kinematic Doppler shifts arising from the orbital motion. Although the specific configuration matters, the general scaling is $v^2/c^2$ for gravitational shifts and $v/c$ for kinematic shifts, where $v$ is the orbital velocity and $c$ is the speed of light.